# The binding status was "DT_NTEXT". The data flow column type is "DBBINDSTATUS_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION"

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, import

I have the following query in Access:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, "2015" As TestYear
FROM Table1
```

I use this query in SQL Server Import/Export tool to get data from Access database into SQL Server database.

I keep getting an error:

> "(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc002f446: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while setting up a binding 
>       for the "TestYear" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT". The data flow column type is "DBBINDSTATUS_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION". 
>        The conversion from the OLE DB type of "DBTYPE_IUNKNOWN" to the destination column type of "DBTYPE_WVARCHAR" might not be supported by
>   this provider.

The destination table column for TestYear is of type  nvarchar.

I checked the source in my import package and the column is shown as LongText. I am not sure why since the column's length is only 4.

Can anyone please help me fix the problem?

Comment: Is that the exact query, or is the `"2015"` actually something else, e.g. a textbox?

Comment: no, this is exact query and "2015" is in fact "2015"

Comment: OK well you may want to try single quotes `'2015'` instead.

Comment: That's  - did not work

Comment: "The destination table column for TestYear is of type nvarchar" What is the width of the destination column? `nvarchar(max)`? `nvarchar(1)` or what?

Comment: nvarchar(4) is the data type in destination table

Comment: Try making it NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: Change the type of the Access database field to Text with 4 characters and then try the Import/Export wizard again.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, in the same tab where you can see that the "2015" column has a LongText datatype you can actually convert it to DT_WSTR which is a unicode widestring which should fit into a NVARCHAR column. If you aren't able to convert it in the tool, adding `CVar("2015") AS TestYear` should also convert it in the MS Access query and allow it to be imported to SQL Server.

If this doesn't work I think we'll need more information on what kind of tool or wizard you were using at the time of this post to provide help.

Comment: Right. But the post may still be useful to someone else. Because of its votes it was pretty far up the "Unanswered" feed

Comment: you said "we'll need more information on what kind of tool or wizard you were using at the time of this post to provide help". Well, I do not remember what was I working on 4 years ago, so i do not see how that comment can be helpful as I have no answer for you

Comment: It's fine if you don't remember, I think my answer stands on its own. The answer would just be more comprehensive if you remember the wizard - but it's not necessary.